# Error: Can't extract columns that don't exist. When using separate function from tidyr package

Tags: r, tidyr

Any help would be MUCH appreciated! I've included solutions I've tried at the end of this post after explaining the error I'm getting. Thank you in advance!

I'm trying to separate a newly added column into 4 separate columns based on a "_" separator as follows (code shows addition of column and separation of that column).

```
library(tidyverse)
library(openxlsx)
library(dplyr)
   ################### Formats raw data input into usable tibble that will be called throughout code ####################
# Adds a `meta` column to the tables with the filename of the file.
ldf_p <- mapply(function(x, y) mutate(x, meta = y), 
               x = ldf_p, 
               y = filenames_poin, 
               SIMPLIFY = FALSE)

# Breaks up the meta column to separate meta information.
tbl_p <- bind_rows(ldf_p)

tbl_p <- tbl_p %>% separate(col = "meta", 
                         sep = "_", 
                         into = c("MUID", "Con", "State", "AirType")) %>%
 mutate(MUID = as_factor(MUID))
```

A snapshot of the head of tbl_p is included below, and you can clearly see the "meta" column included at the bottom. When tbl_p is open this column is present with the desired data.

```
# A tibble: 28,390 x 19
   ...1  `Baseline (V)` `TStart (s)` `TEnd (s)` `Width (ms)` `Height (V)` `SlopeRise (V/s…
   <chr> <chr>          <chr>        <chr>      <chr>        <chr>        <chr>           
 1 1     0              1086.085     1086.244   158.9999999… 1.546670718… 0.0221479367068…
 2 2     0              1086.403     1086.565   162.0000000… 1.535335140… 0.0203560460742…
 3 3     0              1086.718     1086.883   164.9999999… 1.513617013… 0.0194694321866…
 4 4     0              1087.029     1087.19    161.0000000… 1.511392793… 0.0188157590977…
 5 5     0              1087.35      1087.517   167.0000000… 1.531234104… 0.0235031371974…
 6 6     0              1087.674     1087.829   154.9999999… 1.469163170… 0.0211227833350…
 7 7     0              1087.979     1088.144   164.9999999… 1.545739318… 0.0231538763150…
 8 8     0              1088.293000… 1088.46    166.9999999… 1.503279218… 0.0213396815432…
 9 9     0              1088.607     1088.788   181.0000000… 1.533299466… 0.0206839043055…
10 10    0              1088.928     1089.099   170.9999999… 1.491114158… 0.0172873396449…
# … with 28,380 more rows, and 12 more variables: `SlopeFall (V/s)` <chr>, `Sel
#   Duration` <chr>, Freq <chr>, `Avg Period` <chr>, `O2 Mean` <chr>, `CO2 Mean` <chr>, `Temp
#   Mean` <chr>, `Body Temp Linear C` <chr>, `Body Temp Avg C` <chr>, `TV cal mL` <chr>,
#   longname <chr>, meta <chr>
```

When running the final section of the code to separate the meta column in the R platform, it works perfectly. However, when this code is run in a pipeline through terminal, there is an error that I have traced down to the separate function. Below is the full error message with backtrace.

```
Error: Can't extract columns that don't exist.
✖ The column `meta` doesn't exist.
Backtrace:
     █
  1. ├─base::source("~/Desktop/papr/import_data.R")
  2. │ ├─base::withVisible(eval(ei, envir))
  3. │ └─base::eval(ei, envir)
  4. │   └─base::eval(ei, envir)
  5. ├─`%>%`(...)
  6. │ ├─base::withVisible(eval(quote(`_fseq`(`_lhs`)), env, env))
  7. │ └─base::eval(quote(`_fseq`(`_lhs`)), env, env)
  8. │   └─base::eval(quote(`_fseq`(`_lhs`)), env, env)
  9. │     └─`_fseq`(`_lhs`)
 10. │       └─magrittr::freduce(value, `_function_list`)
 11. │         └─function_list[[i]](value)
 12. │           ├─tidyr::separate(...)
 13. │           └─tidyr:::separate.data.frame(...)
 14. │             └─tidyselect::vars_pull(names(data), !!enquo(col))
 15
Execution halted
```

I have tried to rename the column, set an empty vector for "meta" before adding the column, setting empty vectors for the desired final columns, ungrouping just before the separate function, and checking for masked functions. Nothing has worked so far and I'm having trouble finding any other questions similar to this on this website to try and use the solutions from. Any help would be greatly appreciated! If more information is needed please let me know - I'm unsure if I have provided everything necessary for an answer as this is my first time asking a question! Thank you in advance!

Screenshot of format of ldf_p:
[Screenshot of data format for ldf_p](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UhSVt.png)

Comment: `separate` is part of the tidyverse.  So you don't put column names in quotes because of non-standard evaluation. `separate(col = meta, sep = "_", into = c("MUID", "Con", "State", "AirType"))` should do the trick.

Comment: Can you clarify what is causing the problem? Where is the coding working and where is it not? i.e. is it working in RStudio? How exactly are you running it in the terminal?

Comment: @Limey I have tried this solution as well, to no avail.

Comment: @RobertWilson Sure! The code is working in the RStudio platform. So, when I manually call in the folder that contains all of my data files and run the code manually, it works fine. It is only when I use my pipeline to automatically assign the folder for R to find my files (the only change in the run) that this particular section is not working. I'm running in the terminal using argparse to drop in my folder location. From there, it runs a pipeline that just sources each of my sequential R code files that each perform different parts of the analysis. Does this help?

Comment: @savvy Have you tried adding `print(names(ldf_p))` to your script?

Comment: `tibble(w=c("A-B-C", "D-E-F")) %>% separate(w, sep="-", into=c("X", "Y", "Z"))` works for me, so the problem is either elsewhere or down to environment/version, etc.  Would you post the output from `dput(tbl_p %>% select(meta) %>% head())` please?

Comment: @Limey Sure! ```> dput(tbl_p %>% select(meta) %>% head())
structure(list(meta = c("M17021_Con_Cal_CO2.xlsx", "M17021_Con_Cal_CO2.xlsx", 
"M17021_Con_Cal_CO2.xlsx", "M17021_Con_Cal_CO2.xlsx", "M17021_Con_Cal_CO2.xlsx", 
"M17021_Con_Cal_CO2.xlsx")), row.names = c(NA, -6L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"))```

Comment: ... and please try `tidyr::separate(col = meta, ...` to rule out a package conflict.

Comment: @RobertWilson I have not. When I run that, it says "NULL", but it's because its a list of tibbles. I've included a screenshot of the structure of ldf_p to the original post.

Comment: @Limey Tried that as well :)

Comment: Running my `separate` on the results of your `dput` works for me.  The problem must be elsewhere.  Restart R, try again?

Comment: @savvy your could try `print(names(bind_rows(ldf_p))`. My guess is that reading the files in is the problem, not separate.

Comment: Thank you @RobertWilson! That was, indeed, the issue. :) I really appreciate all of y'alls help! @Limey